# What does "such an introduction" refer to?

Tags: reference

> Within the United States, they are commonly taken from one area to another, both legally and illegally, to restock hunting areas **and, presumably, because people simply want them to be part of their local fauna.** Their appearance and subsequent flourishing in Utah's Great Salt Lake valley within the last 40 years appears to be **from such an introduction**. (From TOEFL)

Why does "such an introduction" refer to "and, presumably, because people simply want them to be part of their local fauna"?

This seems confusing, as the preceding context mentions a series of reasons for the introduction.

Comment: "such an introduction" means "taken by people" for one or more of the stated reasons, as opposed to *natural* migration to Salt Lake Valley.

Comment: "presumably, because people simply want them to be part of their local fauna" means some people relocate raccoons only because they *like them*, and not for any other reason (such as wanting to shoot them).